# ¿Cómo puedo plantear el producto de dos números mediante una suma repetitiva utilizando jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bucle-for, botón, while

¡Hola! Estoy intentando resolver algunos problemas utilizando estructuras de control repetitivas usando la librería jQuery y quería saber ¿cómo podría mostrar y representar el producto de dos números ingresados sumando? Por ejemplo, 2 * 3 representado de manera que el producto se obtenga mediante esta operación: 2 + 2 + 2 y viceversa.

Mi primer pensamiento fue usar la funcionalidad FOR porque pensé que sería más conveniente, pero no sabría ¿cómo sumar el primer número por la *cantidad* exacta que se ingrese del segundo número? Al prinicipio pensé que quizás si inicializaba un contador por cero para un WHILE se podría ir contando dicha cantidad, pero parece que eso no funcionó.

Les puedo dejar el código como referencia, decidí que la estructura DO-WHILE sería más apropriada. También me parece que el planteamiento sería correcto, pero aún así no ejecuta correctamente:

```
let num1;
let num2;
let suma = 0;
let producto;

$("#btnIngresar").click(determinarProducto);
function determinarProducto(){
    num1 = Number($("#txtNum1").val());
    num2 = Number($("#txtNum2").val());
    do{
        suma = suma + num1;
        num1++;
    }while(num1 <= num2);

    console.log(suma);
}
```

También el HTML si les parece relevante:

```
<body>
    <label for="txtNum1">Número 1:</label>
    <input type="text" id="txtNum1">
    <label for="txtNum2">Número 2:</label>
    <input type="text" id="txtNum2">
    <input type="button" value="Ingresar" id="btnIngresar">
    <p id="pResultado"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

puedes usar un bucle for y sumar strings, con una condicion para verificar que no se coloque un simbolo de suma demas, espero te ayude:

```
    $("#btnIngresar").click(determinarProducto);

    function determinarProducto(){

        num1 = Number($("#txtNum1").val());
        num2 = Number($("#txtNum2").val());
        producto="";
        for(var i = 0; i < num2; i++){ //2 hasta 3
        producto += String(num1);
        if (i<num2-1){
            producto += "+";
        }
        }

        producto+="=";
        producto+=String(num1*num2);
        $("#pResultado").append(producto);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Eso se realiza con un FOR de toda la vida, así:

```js
let num1 = 2;
let num2 = 3;
let suma = 0;
function determinarProducto(){
    for(i=0; i<num2;i++){
        suma = suma + num1;
    }
    console.log(suma);
}
determinarProducto();
```